# spring boot application with JDK 14 fails to start. no error either

Tags: spring-boot, java-14

I am upgrading
(JDK 8  + spring boot application (2.1.0.RELEASE)) TO
(JDK 14 + spring boot application (2.3.3.RELEASE))

I am using --enable-preview as part of java command but it silently fails. can't see any logger stmts either. --verbose option is not throwing any error nor warning.

any help?

Thanks for responses. Here are more details.
I use maven to compile and use java directly to run it (thru a shell script) **java -jar ./target/fat_00.1.jar**

Why I am doing both (spring FM + JDK)  at same time?
upgrading JDK kind of forced me to upgrade SFM 2.1 to 2.3 (latest)

what else I tried?
I tried "--enable-preview" while compiling (by changing maven pom maven-compiler-plugin plugin) and adding to "java" command prompt

** java -verbose --enable-preview  -jar ./target/fat_00.1.jar**

But none of them give any clue. biggest problem is my spring application exits without any error.

IF I upgrade ONLY spring FW keeping JDK1.8 I get following error:

**findById(java.lang.Long) in com.model.repository.MyRepository clashes with findById(ID) in org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository**

I understand the error its throwing, but does it mean it has no backward compatibility?

How do I find what's going on? without any error thrown anywhere, it is really frustrating.

Comment: You made two upgrades in the same time. So now it fails we don't know it's from the JDK upgrade or the Spring Boot upgrade. How do you launch it ? From your IDE ? From Maven ? From the built jar archive ?

Comment: Can you add the [option](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html) `-e` or `-X` to get more information?

Comment: is this when running in an IDE, or cmd, the command to start?